# Using <> in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have come across  <> used in a statement conditions a few times. Example:

```
SELECT param, d.param
FROM panel p join object d on p.id=d.id 
WHERE param IS NOT NULL and param<>''
```

Let me confirm the statement above has not been tested, it mimics some of the statements that I have come across.

My question is, what is the meaning of the the diamond **<>** condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<>` is like `NOT .. = ..` and `!=`. It means not equal.

[MySQL comparison operators - not equal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

Answer (score 2):

its the opposite of "equal" so it is "not equal".

in C it is `!=`

so in your question it means `param` is not a empty string